# How to overload System.Math methods with custom type

Tags: c#, overloading

I'm currently working on some custom type `Unit` I want other users to be able to do math operations with (sin, cos, ln, etc.).

What I want to do is to overload mathematical functions from `System.Math` to take `Unit` as arguments so when users code they don't have to use two different static methods (`Math.Sin()` and `Unit.Sin()`) from two classes to do math with doubles and `Unit` in the same expression. I want to keep it simple to whoever wants to use my class.

How to overload `System.Math` or is there any other ways to achieve my goal?

Comment: Your question is unclear. What does your `Unit.Sin()` method look like? Why is it similar enough to the `Math.Sin()` method that you feel it should look identical in code that uses it? If your `Unit` type delegates to the `Math` methods themselves, you could just use implicit conversion. If the `Unit` type code is significantly different from the `Math` code, overloading `Math` methods would be a really bad idea even if it were possible (which it's not). Please clarify the question, including providing a [mcve] that show exactly what you want to do.

Answer (score 3):

Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Thanks for your question.

As with most things ".Net" there's several ways to accomplish this.  I'd use [user defined conversion operators](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/user-defined-conversion-operators).

By using conversion operators, your `Unit` Type can be converted to other data types.

For example, if you want to perform Math.Sin using a a `Unit`, you would create an explict or implicit conversion operator.

```
public struct Unit
{
    private readonly double value;

    public Unit(double value)
    {
        this.value = value;
    }

    public static implicit operator double(Unit d) => d.value;
    public static explicit operator Unit(double b) => new Unit(b);
}
```

As a result `Math.Sin(double)` can now accept a Unit.

```
var unit = new Unit(1d);
var sin = Math.Sin(unit);
Console.WriteLine(sin.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
```

If this doesn't answer your question, please tell us more about the `Unit` Type.  Feel free to paste your existing source into your original question.

Comment: This is the correct approach. Design your type (`Unit`) to behave as a primitive type and allow implicit conversions to/from the existing numeric types.

Answer (score 0):

Gabrik is right that you can't just overload `System.Math`. Another solution would be to completely wrap `System.Math` with your own class. Since I assume the primary issue with combining doubles and `Unit` is that `Unit` will need to have some form of conversion happen first, you would create overloads of some of the methods that would take in `Unit` as a parameter in any of the combinations that would be valid.

It may seem like more work than simply overloading particular methods, but the majority of the time consuming work will be the same as if that was possible. The remaining methods, which you wouldn't be overloading anyways, would simply call to the underlying method on `System.Math`. You could generate all that code through any number of techniques available for rapid code generation.